# Changing Heroku version from gem to toolbelt

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have downloaded the Heroku toolbelt a few times but whenever I run

```
heroku version
```

I am getting

```
heroku-gem/1.6.3
```

I have tried to uninstall the heroku gem but I can't seem to use the heroku toolbelt. What's the correct process to use the toolbelt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's likely coming from a Gemfile that is including the `heroku` gem. Remove it from there.

Alternatively you could include the toolbelt higher in the `PATH` environment variable than your ruby gems.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more for those of us who are familiar with heroku but don't work with Ruby? (Note that Heroku supports Python, Java, PHP, and a few other languages as well.)

Comment: I can't really because I don't know how your system is setup. It might use rbenv, it might use rvm, it might use the system ruby. Whichever the case, you should be able to find where the binary is by running `which heroku`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, this what I did:

1. Install the `heroku-toolbelt` from the webpage.
2. go to `/usr/local/heroku/bin` and run `./heroku version` this will throw the version of the current bin, problably this is the version you want to use.
3. run `which heroku` this will throw you a **path**, if the **path** is diferent that `/usr/local/heroku/bin` then just: `rm -rf path`
4. restart your console/terminal run `heroku version`
5. if dosn't work probably you need to add `/usr/local/heroku/` to your **$PATH**.
6. restart and thats all

I was using oh-my-zshell with the heroku plugin which gave me the error and this is how i solve it, hope work for you.

**@UPDATE**

I restart and suddenly I had the same error again :/ and I fixed by:

`gem uninstall heroku` and `rbenv rehash`